# Angular/Ui-router - Head Meta Tags filled with DOM tree

Tags: angularjs, meta, bootstrapping

can anyone help me understand why when I bootstrap angular in the html tag, each meta tag has the DOM of the app? I'm working on dynamic meta tags but the situation exists simply by bootstrapping on html instead of body.

Or can anyone verify that this is normal, won't give me a performance issue, and should be ignored?

[image]

Here's the start of the module.config function:

```
angular.module('numetal')
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        'use strict';

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('metal', {
                url: '',
                template: '<layout></layout>',
                abstract: true,
                controller: function (Facts) {
                    var vm = this;
                    vm.a = Facts.api;
                    vm.d = Facts.data;
                    vm.s = Facts.state;
                    vm.u = Facts.ux;
                },
                controllerAs: 'metal',
                data: function (State) {
                    return {
                        head: {
                            title: 'Forging Technology - Serving Vancouver with Superior Metalwork',
                                keywords: State.params,
                                description: "your meta description",
                                robots: "index,follow",
                                canonical: 'http://www.mySite.tld/home'
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('metal.home', {
                url: '/',
                template: '<posts></posts>',
                data: function (State) {
                    return {
                        head: {
                            title: 'Forging Technology Proudly Serving Vancouver with Superior Metalwork',
                            keywords: State.params,
                            description: "Posts from Forging Technology, Vancouver Metalwork",
                            robots: "index,follow",
                            canonical: 'http://www.mySite.tld/home'
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Thank you all!

Comment: I got the same issue, did you fix it ?